# Pandas Dataframe dropping rows and setting column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
      1     2       3 
0
NaN   ingr   contr   count
2.0   water  0.02    275
3.0   oil    0.23    11
.....
```

and I would like to transfer it to this:

```
ingr   contr   count
water  0.02    275
oil    0.23    11
....
```

I tried to use `pd.drop` and `pd.set_index()` etc but I cannot figure out how to do this. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

try [iloc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) indexer:

```
In [66]: df
Out[66]:
          1      2      3
NaN    ingr  contr  count
 2.0  water   0.02    275
 3.0    oil   0.23     11

In [67]: df.columns = df.iloc[0]

In [68]: df = df.iloc[1:].reset_index()

In [69]: df
Out[69]:
nan  index   ingr contr count
0      2.0  water  0.02   275
1      3.0    oil  0.23    11
```

PS but it would be much more efficient to read your data properly from the very beginning using `header`, `skiprows`, etc. parameters of the [read_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)/read_excel/read_table/et.c functions

Comment: Thank you MaxU you helped me a lot with this!

Comment: How does df.iloc works? Because you picked iloc[0] and this referred to the column names?

Comment: @Papie, how do you read your data? I think it should be fixed / corrected during the reading

Comment: I read the data from a csv file with: pd.DataFrame.from_csv("./data/svm_contr_all.csv", sep=',',header=None, encoding="ISO-8859-1")

Answer (score 1):

Use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0,:]
print (df.iloc[1:,:].reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1))
     0   ingr contr count
0  2.0  water  0.02   275
1  3.0    oil  0.23    11
```

If dont need old index add parameter `drop=True`:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0,:]
print (df.iloc[1:,:].reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(None, axis=1))
    ingr contr count
0  water  0.02   275
1    oil  0.23    11
```

If you need first column as index use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0,:]
print (df.iloc[1:,:].set_index('ingr').rename_axis(None, axis=1).rename_axis(None))
      contr count
water  0.02   275
oil    0.23    11
```